Does the word vaishnava appear even once in Srimad Bhagavatam?
Does the word Vaishnava appear even once in Srimad Bhagavatam?
Has anyone come across the term in Srimad Bhagavatam?

The word Vaishnava is also found in vedas, in the Taittiriya samhita of Yajur Veda 1.2.13 - https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_veda/taittirIyasamhitA.html

of course:  the famous verse that Siva is the foremost Vaishnava:
https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/12/13/16/
ŚB 12.13.16

निम्नगानां यथा गङ्गा देवानामच्युतो यथा ।
वैष्णवानां यथा शम्भु: पुराणानामिदं तथा ॥ १६ ॥


nimna-gānāṁ yathā gaṅgā
devānām acyuto yathā
vaiṣṇavānāṁ yathā śambhuḥ
purāṇānām idam tathā


Just as the Gaṅgā is the greatest of all rivers, Lord Acyuta the supreme among deities and Lord Śambhu [Śiva] the greatest of Vaiṣṇavas, so Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam is the greatest of all Purāṇas.


Thanks I want to know if there is any verse that supports leaving a bad guru apart from one mentioned in narada pancharatra

Yes, the word Vaishnava many times. You might find this tool useful:
https://vedabase.io/en/search/synonyms/?original=Vaisnav&original_choices=contains&hierarchy=%2F0001%2F0001%2F0001%2F0003%2F0002

Thanks sir I want to know if there is any verse that supports leaving a bad guru apart from one mentioned in narada pancharatra

My pleasure. This is described in a Gaudiya Vaishnava scripture named Krishna Bhajanamrita. bvmlu.org/SKB/index.html Please refer to verses 64-65. Not aware of any Puranic verses. Will need to search.
